# On expedia, how can I tell if a flight on multiple airlines is a single ticket or multiple tickets?

Tags: expedia

I'm looking at purchasing the following trip from expedia:

[image]

How can I tell if this is a single ticket for both the GOL and TAP legs or multiple tickets, one for GOL and one for TAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This flight was 1 ticket checked all the way through, but we don't know how we could tell.

On the next page Expedia indicates it's "1 ticket: roundtrip", but who knows if that's just their summary text or if it means it's actually one ticket.

[image]

After purchasing the ticket the GOL legs turned into Varig, but the flight number are GOL

[image]

Sorry for the screenshot from a phone, my sibling purchasing the ticket is in the Amazon and the phone internet works so much better than computer internet that it's actually easier to take screenshots this way.

None of the other sites could put together this itinerary.

Looking up the locator numbers on GOL and TAPs website, the tickets are checked all the way through both airlines.

Answer (score 2):

Booking a ticket on "Multiple Airlines" means you would receive two (or more) separate tickets. Which in most cases means you will have to recheck luggage on layovers and risk missing the second flight if the first one is delayed.

The same terminology also applies on other websites, such as Kayak.

Source: previously booking such a ticket. I will try to get an official confirmation from Expedia shortly.

Comment: Gol doesn't really interline with much of anybody. So these will be separate tickets and you'll have to transfer yourself and your baggage in Belem. Fortunately your first leg is domestic and this won't take long. It could be a problem coming back the other direction though.

Comment: I would find that odd; what do they do when it's multiple airlines on one ticket, then?

Comment: For BOD to SDJ which I do often on multiple airlines/one ticket, Expedia displays "Multiple airlines" as on OP's screenshot. I strongly suspect Expedia also sells it on one ticket, otherwise the fare would probably be higher than what it shows me.