# Are flights undertaken by GOL Transportes Aereos via KLM considered to be a single ticket / booking?

Tags: tickets, transit-visas, klm

I have booked tickets from Germany to Uruguay.

The major Airline for the trip is **KLM**.
There is a stop at Brazil's Sao Paolo GRU airport from where I have a flight to Montevideo. This particular flight is undertaken by **GOL Transportes Aereos**. The connection is shown below:

[image: Flight Connection]

The flight number is **KL9264** which falls under KLM but I am anxious to know if this is a single ticket or not.

#### Reason

- I have an Indian Passport, and I cross checked with the Brazillian Embassy in India on whether I need a Transit Visa in Brazil. Their reply was the following:

> Travelers transiting through Brazilian airports to other countries, whenever the onward flight is booked under a separate ticket and/or different code need to have a transit visa.

Does the connection mentioned above constitute a Single ticket? As was the question previously asked [On Expedia How Can I Tell if A Flight on Multiple Airlines is a single ticket or not](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66718/on-expedia-how-can-i-tell-if-a-flight-on-multiple-airlines-is-a-single-ticket-o), the accepted answer came only after the **OP** had traveled and not beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly a single ticket. If you had separate tickets, the airline would not show them together (and the KL codeshare probably cannot be bought as a separate ticket at all).

What Brazil is interested in is whether you'll need to go through their immigration control. When you're on a single ticket it means that you will not need to go through immigration to pick up and recheck baggage, and that you won't risk being stranded in Sao Paulo because your incoming flight was late and you missed your connection (or the second airline somehow didn't honor your ticket).

Comment: I am a bit worried though, since I think as an Indian Passport holder I won't be able to apply for a brazilian transit visa in Germany. I have sent emails to KLM regarding a clarification on this thing but It is just getting a bit nervy

Comment: @Shan-Desai: Why do you think you would need a transit visa? The Brazilian embassy explicitly told you you don't.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly: GRU to MVD is different country code but that shouldn't be a problem since I have a single ticket booked with less that 5 hour stopover and I do not need to go through immigration and baggage collection?

Comment: @Shan-Desai: I don't know what you mean by "different country code" or why that would influence the fact that as a transit passenger at GRU on a single booking you do not need a transit visa.

Comment: No, no I am not saying they are lying but I was just tangled up in the way the sentence with `and/or` is formed. I read it as `onward flights is booked under separate ticket OR different code` which got me confused. Where code being `GRU` and `MVD` in this case.

Comment: @Shan-Desai: What makes you think "different code" means airport designations such as GRU as MVD? It would make no sense at all for the embassy to say you can transit without a visa unless you're going to a different airport than the one you're transiting in. Transiting _inherently means_ ending up at a different airport than the one you're changing planes at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84146/discussion-between-shan-desai-and-henning-makholm).

Comment: I agree it is a single ticket but the flights have different codes KL 9624 versus KL 0791 which I believe means the OP needs a transit visa.

Comment: @mdewey: No. that makes no sense either. _Of course_ transits are between different flight numbers. It would be completely meaningless to say that one can transit without a visa as long as one leaves on the same flight one flew in on.

Comment: I believe the sentence means `booked under a separate ticket or __booking code__` which makes sense as one might then need to collect baggage and go to immigration checks once again making it necessary to have a transit visa

Comment: I agree but in that case the advice from the Brazilian embassy does not make much sense either since they mention different codes and as you state you do not usually transit onto the same plane with the same code.

Comment: @mdewey: That's only if you speak a secret personal language in which "code" means flight number.

Comment: I would never the less try sending an email again to the Embassy regarding clarification of the word `code` in the reply and what does it actually imply. No doubt that @HenningMakholm is right but I might as well send one more harmless email to see if this could be phrased more concretely.

Comment: @HenningMakholm and @mdewey, just got a confirmation from the Airline that the booking I have made is a single booking under the same booking code. I have also sent an email to the Embassy of Brazil regarding clarification of the word `code` and would probably post it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

### Confirmation

#### Flights

- I took the time to contact KLM via their email and WhatsApp platforms where I sent the following information to them:

  ```
  Full Name, Booking Code, Ticket Number, Flight Route, Flight Number, Travel Dates, Email
  ```
- I mentioned in the email that I wish to confirm whether the flight ticket booked is a **single reservation/ticket** and I received a prompt reply from them stating it is a single reservation with the exact code mentioned by them.

The replies where within windows of the 6 hours, which was fantastic.

#### Brazilian Consulate in New-Delhi

- I sent an email asking for clarification for the word `code` in their following statement:

  > Travelers transiting through Brazilian airports to other countries, whenever the onward flight is booked under a separate ticket and/or **different code** need to have a transit visa.

Their reply was the following:

> different code refers to **different PNR**. If your ticket does not fall under the requriment of a transit visa then you should not have a problem.

So as mentioned @HenningMakholm I do not require a Transit Visa.

(**Better to be safe than sorry!** since flying out to Brazil and then being denied boarding would be utterly disheartening!!)