# Japan transit on a Philippines passport

Tags: visas, transit, japan

From a non-official source https://visaguide.world/asia/japan-visa/transit/ is information that a person does not need a visa obtained in advance to transit through Japan. The main requirement is a confirmed onward ticket on the same calendar day. I am trying to make plans for a travel companion that will be on a Philippines passport. Transit through the U.S. seems to require a consulate interview for Philippines passport holders so we will try to avoid transit through the U.S..

I would like to confirm this with an official source if you would be able to answer with a reference. Obviously I am concerned about the non-official source being out-of-date or inaccurate.

Edit to add details: The outbound booking is a single Expedia itinerary, Manila to Narita to Dallas to Toronto. The return booking is a single (but different) Expedia itinerary, Toronto to Haneda to Manila. Looking to make a change to avoid the U.S. (Dallas).

Comment: To answer, we need to know the full itinerary, or you can check yourself via https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

Comment: @Traveller We booked Manila to Tokyo Narita to Dallas F.W. to Toronto but because of the consulate interview for the U.S. we are likely to change this ticket.

Comment: Would both flights be into/from NRT? Would they be on the same ticket? https://www.emirates.com/fr/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=ph&destination=ca&transit=jp

Comment: @jcaron Both flights? We would like to transit through Narita.  The return trip is transits through Haneda. The return was booked on another itinerary if that matters. We are looking to rebook without the U.S transit.

Comment: Will your outbound flights be booked as one itinerary, that is, a single PNR? If you are changing airlines your transit needs may be different

Comment: @Traveller Outbound is one itinerary from Expedia. A change of airlines through Japan is very likely judging from what I've seen.  I'm not familiar with the PNR acronym.

Comment: PNR  = passenger name record. Does your itinerary require you to collect your luggage and clear immigration to transfer to your onward flight?

Comment: @Traveller The Narita transit is in Terminal 2, arriving in Terminal 2 and departing in Terminal 2.  Japan Airlines arriving.  American Airlines departing. I do not know the implications.

Comment: The implications revolve around whether you can transit airside, having checked your baggage through to your final destination, or whether you need to recheck your luggage on layover(s) and transit landside https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66718/on-expedia-how-can-i-tell-if-a-flight-on-multiple-airlines-is-a-single-ticket-o

Comment: @Traveller  There will only be carry-ons.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Traveller The Haneda transit on the return will also involve only carry-ons. There will be a change from Air Canada (Haneda Terminal 3) to Philippine Airlines (Haneda Terminal 3).